# Apache: multiple domains handling

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

So I use following schema to handle multiple sites on my apache:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80>

# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/%0/cgi-bin

</VirtualHost>
```

Therefore, if a client go to www.example.com, it will actually point to /var/www/www.example.com/doc/, which is good. However, what if the client go to example.com? It will point to /var/www/example.com/doc, which is not what we want.

So my question is: is there any better schema for that? Or what should I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends what behavior you want to see.

If you want for the `www.example.com` site to be redirected to `example.com` or vice-versa, this can be implemented in `RewriteRule` settings.  For example (these go inside your `<VirtualHost>`):

```
# Send www.example.com to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Send www.other.example.com to other.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.other\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://other.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To knock the `www` off of every name:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to serve the content to both names, then you have a couple options.

- If you'll only ever have a pretty simple set of domains, then change the constructed docroot to not care about `www`.

  ```
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2/docs
  ```

  ...which points to the docroot at `/var/www/example/docs`.
- If you need to get a little more creative with the subdomains (like having a `b.example.com` and `www.b.example.com` that point to their own site, not the `example.com` one), symlinks might be a good approach.

  ```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  ```

  ...and create a symlink at `/var/www/www.example.com` pointing to the directory at  `/var/www/example.com`.

Comment: Could you please advise how to use RewriteRule you mentioned above? An example will be much helpful, thanks!

Comment: @cache Added an example for the redirect option.

Comment: Thanks, what should I change to make it generic rather than only applied for www.example.com?

Comment: @cache Edited that in too.